# Downloading 270,451 pictures from Flickr

Tags: flickr

I need to download 270,451 pictures from Flickr. They are two years old (I have the IDs, and I need to download those specific pictures). I guess there is a download limit.

Do you think I can make it in few days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Downloadr;

http://janten.com/downloadr/

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/backup-your-flickr-photos-with-downloadr/

and Flickr Backup;

http://sourceforge.net/projects/flickrbackup/

Hope this helps.